# CMS Made Simple: Why does home page return a 404 under www subdomain?

Tags: html, htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, cpanel

Anyone know why my homepage won't load with the `www` prefix.

Links such as

```
www.example.com/about-us
```

will load fine

but

```
www.example.com
```

returns a 404.

Every page works including the home page if I leave out the `www`. The site has CMS Made Simple in the backend and has a root_url set without the `www`. The DNS has a CNAME to the `www` too.

As Requested here is the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^gallery(/((([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(/(\d+))?)/?)?)?$ index.php?page=77&groupId=$4&showpage=$6 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your .htaccess? Otherwise it's entirely speculation...

Comment: Could this be it?:  _"...has a root_url set **without** the www"_

Comment: It depends on the 404 generated. If it's handled by the CMS and outputted accordingly, then that's a likely possibility. If it's a raw server 404, then the CMS settings shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: its a raw 4040 generated by the host and not the one generated by the cms. i tried the root_url with the www but it makes no difference.

Comment: It appears that you need to set correct CNAME www to @  
And then wait until DNS propagation.

Comment: maybe a silly question sorry if it is, but what is the significance of the @ here. I have a cname to the www version of the site, do you mean a different entry when you specifies the @. thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi Guys this ones solved it seems to have been a weird propogation issue as it worked on my laptop at another persons house.

Answer (score 1):

Might it be the fact that you have a last rewrite flag on the first rule?
I would remove the `L` from `[NC, QSA, L]`.

```
RewriteRule ^gallery(/((([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(/(\d+))?)/?)?)?$ index.php?page=77&groupId=$4&showpage=$6 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I believe the `L` flag will stop the rules below from being parsed, may be wrong though?
We have any .htaccess wiz's out there?

Comment: That rule would only apply to gallery pages, and the `L` flag only stops mod_rewrite if the rule matches. So it's not the problem. The problem was a DNS propagation error as specified in the comments. The OP just chose not to post that solution and accept it as an answer.